# How to return values from a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, return, return-value

I'm pulling in an rss feed in a new thread (class that implements runnable, shown below) I want to use the strings I get from the rss feed and return them to the main class. The main class simply runs the thread like so

`new Thread(new RssParse()).start();`

I'm having a really hard time finding ways to return these strings that were cut out of the xml to the main class. Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
public class RssParse implements Runnable  {

            private static final String MY_DEBUG_TAG = "pfaff";


            public void run(){

            System.out.println("1");
            URL iotd;
            try{

                iotd = new URL("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/image_of_the_day.rss");//set URl
                BufferedReader in;//new BufferedReader
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iotd.openStream()));//get rss

                XmlPullParserFactory factory;
                factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();//new factory


                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser xpp;
                xpp = factory.newPullParser();
                xpp.setInput(in);


                int eventType;
                eventType = xpp.getEventType();

                System.out.println(eventType+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

            while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

                switch(eventType){

                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    String tagName=xpp.getName();
                    System.out.println(tagName+" "+xpp.getDepth());
                    if(tagName.equals("title")&& xpp.getDepth()==4){//depth is specific to this certain rss feed, there are multiple tags with the same names
                        String title=xpp.nextText();// I want to return title and a few other strings but can't figure out how to do this when dealing with threads.
                        System.out.println(title);
                    }

                    break;

                }
                eventType=xpp.next();
            }//switch


                in.close();//close BufferedReader
            } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(XmlPullParserException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }           
      }//method


}//class
```

Comment: In Java 5 you would use a `Future`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to suggest [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You have to override `doInBackground(Params...)` and `onPostExecute(Result)` of AsyncTask in your sub-class.

Tutorial : [Android Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, looking into it right now, thanks!

Comment: Googles example is a little confusing. Do you know of any better ones?

Comment: This worked great thanks, can you pass more than one type though? I invoke like the thread like so....     new RssParseSync(this).execute(title,description,date);   where all 3 params are strings, any way to pass 3 strings and a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

you can use handler to post it in to main thread

```
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
 {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
            public void run() {
                progress.setProgress(value);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

};

Comment: Inside your run method the object you want to post in to main thread there you can place this code